# Перенос данных из String в Date

Tags: java, дата

вопрос по сохранению строки в формат даты.

В списке 12 элементом является строка формата "yyyy-MM-dd-HH", пытаюсь сохранить её в таком же формате (yyyy-MM-dd-HH), но уже используя тип даты, а не строки (для переноса в базу).

Проблема в том что сейчас формат меняется(как видно на картинке при выводе в консоль), в чём может быть проблема и как сохранить изначальный формат?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получили дату правильно - но ее при выводе в консоль снова не форматируете. Поэтому она выводится так как на скриншоте. Если хотите увидеть более читаемый вывод - надо снова форматировать. Используйте у SimpleDateFormat метод format

Comment: Спасибо, думал где то ошибка)